# Why do we need intermediate directory?

Tags: visual-studio

I know the output directory puts exe in it, but I don't understand the use of the files inside of an intermediate directory, do we also need those to run too?

Comment: The project directory contains the files you need to check-in to source control.  The output directory contains the files you'll want to deploy to the user's machine.  The intermediate directory contains files that fit neither categories, they are needed to build the project.  You don't mind losing them.